# nHibernate 3.0.0.4000 handles bools differently in queries?

Tags: sqlite, nhibernate

I just updated nHibernate from version 3.0.0.1002 to 3.0.0.4000. As soon as I did that many of my queries started failing. One such query is this:

```
var items = (from b in session.Query<InvoiceDetail>() 
                            where b.Customer == AddressedToCustomer && b.IsCreditNote == !addInvoices 
                            orderby b.DueDate , b.InvoiceNumber 
                            select b).ToList();
```

SQL Generated in 3.0.0.1002:

> 2011-02-17 15:55:43,612 DEBUG select
>   invoicedet0_.Id as Id3_,
>   invoicedet0_.InvoiceNumber as
>   InvoiceN2_3_,
>   invoicedet0_.DocumentNumber as
>   Document3_3_,
>   invoicedet0_.DocumentDate as
>   Document4_3_, invoicedet0_.DueDate as
>   DueDate3_,
>   invoicedet0_.DivisionDetails as
>   Division6_3_, invoicedet0_.IsInvoice
>   as IsInvoice3_,
>   invoicedet0_.IsCreditNote as
>   IsCredit8_3_,
>   invoicedet0_.OriginalAmount as
>   Original9_3_, invoicedet0_.Amount as
>   Amount3_, invoicedet0_.LRNo as LRNo3_,
>   invoicedet0_.LRDate as LRDate3_,
>   invoicedet0_.DispatchedBy as
>   Dispatc13_3_, invoicedet0_.CreditDays
>   as CreditDays3_,
>   invoicedet0_.CustomerId as
>   CustomerId3_ from InvoiceDetails
>   invoicedet0_ where
>   ((invoicedet0_.CustomerId is null) and
>   (@p0 is null) or
>   invoicedet0_.CustomerId=@p0) and case
>   when invoicedet0_.IsCreditNote=1 then
>   1 else 0 end=case when @p1=1 then 1
>   else 0 end order by
>   invoicedet0_.DueDate asc,
>   invoicedet0_.InvoiceNumber asc;@p0 =
>   101790 [Type: Int32 (0)], @p1 = False
>   [Type: Int32 (0)]

SQL Generated in 3.0.0.4000:

> 2011-02-17 16:22:15,275 DEBUG select
>   invoicedet0_.Id as Id3_,
>   invoicedet0_.InvoiceNumber as
>   InvoiceN2_3_,
>   invoicedet0_.DocumentNumber as
>   Document3_3_,
>   invoicedet0_.DocumentDate as
>   Document4_3_, invoicedet0_.DueDate as
>   DueDate3_,
>   invoicedet0_.DivisionDetails as
>   Division6_3_, invoicedet0_.IsInvoice
>   as IsInvoice3_,
>   invoicedet0_.IsCreditNote as
>   IsCredit8_3_,
>   invoicedet0_.OriginalAmount as
>   Original9_3_, invoicedet0_.Amount as
>   Amount3_, invoicedet0_.LRNo as LRNo3_,
>   invoicedet0_.LRDate as LRDate3_,
>   invoicedet0_.DispatchedBy as
>   Dispatc13_3_, invoicedet0_.CreditDays
>   as CreditDays3_,
>   invoicedet0_.CustomerId as
>   CustomerId3_ from InvoiceDetails
>   invoicedet0_ where
>   invoicedet0_.CustomerId=@p0 and case
>   when invoicedet0_.IsCreditNote=1 then
>   'true' else 'false' end=case when
>   @p1='true' then 'true' else 'false'
>   end order by invoicedet0_.DueDate asc,
>   invoicedet0_.InvoiceNumber asc;@p0 =
>   101790 [Type: Int32 (0)], @p1 =
>   'False' [Type: String (0)]

I am using a convention to convert bools into ints (true=1, false=0). The previous version is doing this conversion, the newer version isn't. The bool is converted to a string in the newer version, but it should be converted to int according to the convention.

From generated SQL: 
"!addInvoices" is passed as a string in the sql query and int in the previous version: 
3.0.0.1002: @p1 = True [Type: Int32 (0)] 
3.0.0.4000: @p1 = 'True' [Type: String (0)]

Also, the IsCreditNote database field is compared to 'true' and 'false' in the new version, and with 1 and 0 in the previous version.

Secondly, even if I remove the convention, this is the output for two different commands in 3.0.0.4000: 
Insert:

> 2011-02-20 10:18:22,977 DEBUG INSERT
>   INTO InvoiceDetails (InvoiceNumber,
>   DocumentNumber, DocumentDate, DueDate,
>   DivisionDetails, IsInvoice,
>   IsCreditNote, OriginalAmount, Amount,
>   LRNo, LRDate, DispatchedBy,
>   CreditDays, CustomerId) VALUES (@p0,
>   @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7,
>   @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13);
>   select last_insert_rowid();@p0 =
>   9070183358 [Type: Int64 (0)], @p1 =
>   28592879 [Type: Int64 (0)], @p2 =
>   '20110210' [Type: String (0)], @p3 =
>   '20110303' [Type: String (0)], @p4 =
>   NULL [Type: String (0)], @p5 = True
>   [Type: Boolean (0)], @p6 = False
>   [Type: Boolean (0)], @p7 = 2685 [Type:
>   Decimal (0)], @p8 = 2685 [Type:
>   Decimal (0)], @p9 = NULL [Type: String
>   (0)], @p10 = NULL [Type: String (0)],
>   @p11 = NULL [Type: String (0)], @p12 =
>   21 [Type: Int32 (0)], @p13 = 101760
>   [Type: Int32 (0)]

Update:

> 2011-02-20 10:10:13,941 DEBUG select
>   invoicedet0_.Id as Id3_,
>   invoicedet0_.InvoiceNumber as
>   InvoiceN2_3_,
>   invoicedet0_.DocumentNumber as
>   Document3_3_,
>   invoicedet0_.DocumentDate as
>   Document4_3_, invoicedet0_.DueDate as
>   DueDate3_,
>   invoicedet0_.DivisionDetails as
>   Division6_3_, invoicedet0_.IsInvoice
>   as IsInvoice3_,
>   invoicedet0_.IsCreditNote as
>   IsCredit8_3_,
>   invoicedet0_.OriginalAmount as
>   Original9_3_, invoicedet0_.Amount as
>   Amount3_, invoicedet0_.LRNo as LRNo3_,
>   invoicedet0_.LRDate as LRDate3_,
>   invoicedet0_.DispatchedBy as
>   Dispatc13_3_, invoicedet0_.CreditDays
>   as CreditDays3_,
>   invoicedet0_.CustomerId as
>   CustomerId3_ from InvoiceDetails
>   invoicedet0_ where
>   invoicedet0_.CustomerId=@p0 and case
>   when invoicedet0_.IsCreditNote=1 then
>   'true' else 'false' end=case when
>   @p1='true' then 'true' else 'false'
>   end order by invoicedet0_.DueDate asc,
>   invoicedet0_.InvoiceNumber asc;@p0 =
>   107233 [Type: Int32 (0)], @p1 = 'True'
>   [Type: String (0)]

In Inserts, the passed parameter is a Boolean (@p6), and in Selects, the parameter is a String (@p1).

The thing is, I posted this as an [issue on nHibernate JIRA](http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-2540) (actually most of this is copied from that issue thread), but Patrick Earl closed the issue as a non-issue. He said this is the standard behavior.

All the versions of nHibernate before this version behaved correctly. Only this one behaves differently. Can anybody comment is this really a bug, or is Patrick correct and I need to workaround this problem in my database?

**EDIT:**
My database is SQLite and I am using Fluent nHibernate.

Comment: No this is a damn bug, the 'Query' / LINQ Provider is epic fail. It does a LOT of really stupid thing's, selecting a 'MAX()' value does casting, when Criterion does NOT cast the value. The LINQ provider is not production ready in my opinion, I've been using QueryOver since Query has so many issues.

Comment: add a link to the jira issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phill is right. The Query/LINQ provider has issues.

This Criteria/QueryOver API works perfectly:

```
var items = session.QueryOver<InvoiceDetail>()
        .Where(i => i.Customer == AddressedToCustomer)
        .And(i => i.IsCreditNote != addInvoices)
        .OrderBy(i => i.DueDate).Asc
        .ThenBy(i => i.InvoiceNumber).Asc
        .List();
```

And even more surprising is that the developers of the provider just close issues/bugs as non-issues without even looking into them properly. I am planning to replace all `Query<>` calls to `QueryOver<>` calls just to be sure. For a project like nHibernate, this is indeed a pity specially considering developers like me who love linq.

Comment: How about requesting a reopen and link to this question? Would be interesting to see what they say.

Comment: @Yogesh: You will have problems with QueryOver too (it's limited). Linq is pretty new and alien in NH world. Use Criteria API. P.S. I Like LINQ with Lambda too, but LINQ support in NH is poor compared to Criteria API.

Comment: @Alex - QueryOver is a wrapper around Criteria, if something isn't supported then you can just call .UnderlyingCriteria and fallback to legacy Criteria API.

Comment: @Phill: I know that it's a wrapper, and Criteria API is not legacy, it's NH Core and main API, what I was trying to say that QueryOver wraps only 5% of NH query functionality and there is no reason to use.

Comment: @jgauffin: How can I request for a reopen?

Comment: @Alex - I bet it's a lot more than 5%, but either way what they have converted over caters for 95% of everyday queries.

Comment: The issue is not just closed, it's marked as resolved in 3.1. Have you tried 3.1?

Comment: @jgauffin: Read Patrick's reply in the JIRA thread. He thinks the correct behaviour is a bug.

Comment: I've seen this before. Frankly, I don't get why they use string comparisons to compare booleans. For one thing, this would fail if the database used case sensitive comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

If your are using SQL server change column type to bit for boolean values.

Try query substitutions:

```
3.5.4. Query Language Substitution

You may define new NHibernate query tokens using query.substitutions. For example:
query.substitutions true=1, false=0
would cause the tokens true and false to be translated to integer literals in the generated SQL.
query.substitutions toLowercase=LOWER
would allow you to rename the SQL LOWER function.
```